# What is known about homotopy groups of spheres?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

I'm looking for a list/table/survey of what is known (and what is not known) about homotopy groups of spheres, for example:  which are known, which are known stably, which are known primally, non-$0$ etc.

I'm aware of what is on Wikipedia, but I doubt it's exhaustive...

Comment: In terms of the stable homotopy groups of spheres at prime $2$, I think the recent work of Isaksen-Wang-Xu (https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.04511) is the current state of the art.

Comment: Typically these types of questions are closed on Math Overflow, as the discussion is more appropriate for a Wikipedia entry/chat than this forum.  I certainly sympathize with threads like these as I imagine they would have more utility than a Wikipedia page.  Anyhow, this isn't the place for that kind of discussion.

Comment: The efforts put forward to a thread like this are more appropriate for the Wikipedia page. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres

Comment: "What is known about homotopy groups of spheres?"  That it is a difficult and deep problem :-).

Comment: @Ryan I view it as a completely reasonable question, since there is a lot "known to experts" in homotopy theory that is not easy to find. And this is the whole point of MO. Pointing someone to a Wikipedia page not intended for such detailed information is not the most helpful thing.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: These kinds of questions regularly get closed when they concern other topics.  It would be consistent to close the question, but perhaps consistency is not the goal.

Comment: Well, when the person explicitly says they are aware of the content at Wikipedia, and judging by their other questions, aren't exactly a random noob, then pointing them twice to Wikipedia in comments seems a bit odd to me. And I don't view the question as asking for a discussion, either. I have also, in the past, wondered about this question and would like a better reference than WP, namely a decent survey paper, if there is one.